# Landoop/fast-data-dev : Connection to node -1 could not be established

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to use kafka with the docker image `Landoop/fast-data-dev`
I ran the following commands

I started the docker container

`docker run --rm -it -p 2183:2181  -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082  -p 8083:8083 -p 9093:9092 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 landoop/fast-data-dev`

then I started the bash command

```
docker run --rm -it --net=host landoop/fast-data-dev bash
```

then I created a topic

```
kafka-topics --create --zookeeper localhost:2183 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3 --topic my-topic
```

then I tried to send data to the topic

```
kafka-console-producer --broker-list localhost:9093 --topic my-topic
```

but I was receiving the following error

[2018-10-27 20:08:24,655] WARN [Producer clientId=console-producer] Connection to node -1 could not be established. Broker may not be available. (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)

ps: because of "port already allocation" problem I changed the mappings of kafka and zookeeper to 9093 and 2183

Answer (score 0):

You're running the CLI commands *within the container*, so you can't just remap the port on the host. You'll actually need to also set the port within the container on which Kafka runs, using the `BROKER_PORT` variable, in this case.

`docker run --rm -it -p 2183:2181 -p 3030:3030 -p 8081:8081 -p 8082:8082 -p 8083:8083 -p 9093:9093 -e ADV_HOST=127.0.0.1 -e BROKER_PORT=9093 landoop/fast-data-dev`

Otherwise, you still have to use `localhost:9092` within the container even if the external port is 9093, but you never needed to add `-p` flags anyway to expose the ports externally if you were going to start bash within the container to do things.

If you wanted to use applications *outside the container*, see [this blog](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/), which uses Confluent containers, but same concept applies, though the landoop variables are different